# How calculate the singular values of the Neumann series $M=\sum_{n=1}^\infty A^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition, singular-values

Given a matrix $A$, the Neumann series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series is defined as
$$M=\sum_{n=0}^\infty A^n.$$
For a converge $M$, how to calculate the singular value? Is it possible to express the singular values of $M$ by the singular values of $A$?

What I have done:
Since $M$ is converge. $M=(1-A)^{-1}$. We know the singular value of an inverse matrix is the reciprocal of the original matrix. But what's the relationship between the singular values of $A$ and $1-A$?

If not easy, can we give some bound of the singular values with $A$'s singular values?

Comment: Should the series instead begin at $n = 0$? Otherwise, the limit would be $A(I - A)^{-1}$

Comment: We can find these singular values when$A$ is normal, but in general there is no simple relationship between the singular values of $A$ and the singular values of $A + kI$ (for some scalar $k$).

Comment: sorry I updated the questiin

Comment: Stating the obvious: if $\|A\|_2<1$, then $\left\|\sum_{n=0}^\infty A^n\right\|_2\le(1-\|A\|_2)^{-1}$.

Comment: @user1551 Could you please give some proof of this?

Comment: @maple $\|\sum_nA^n\|_2 =\sup_{\|x\|_2=1}\|\sum_nA^nx\|_2\le\sup_{\|x\|_2=1}\sum_n\|A\|_2^n\|x\|_2=\sum_n\|A\|_2^n=(1-\|A\|_2)^{-1}$.